# Converting from 4 digit hexadecimal code point

Tags: vb.net, utf-8

I would like to covert a 4 digit hexadecimal code point to UTF8.

For example:
4e00 to 一

I'm looking for a quick single line solution. I've tried several solutions like this:

```
Dim s1 As String = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(&H28E02)
```

I don't think they are built for my 4 digit code though.

Comment: What does 'convert ... to UTF8' mean? Your example shows the *character* for that codepoint, is that what you mean? The [UTF8 encoding of that codepoint](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=4e00&mode=hex) is `E4 B8 80`, is that what you want?

Comment: Accordingly to [char.convertfromutf32 msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32.aspx#Y0) this method receives a number unicode code point (on this case: U+28E02) and returns a string with the corresponding unicode character (http://graphemica.com/%F0%A8%B8%82).   What you mean by "don't think they are built for my 4 digit code?"

Comment: "E4 B8 80" is the utf8 code unit, I want to covert from the hex code point "4e00" to the actual Chinese character which is "一".

Comment: That because you aren't properly setting the integer value. You're converting U+28E02  not U+4E00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
 Dim s1 As String = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(&H4E00)
```

Comment: Cheers! Mine are all in the 4 digit format, but changing it to `Char.ConvertFromUtf32("&H" + myValue)` seems to work.

Comment: The &Hxxx format on VB defines that the xxx value is in hexadecimal base [Hexadecimal and Octal Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) . what this means is that your values source is in hexadecimal format

Comment: Please note that the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is "&", not "+". You don't want it deciding some day to add zero to your number if it finds it can parse it that way.